# Splitting field of $f(x)=x^2+1$ over $F={\bf Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Note that $f(x)=x^2+1=(x+1)^2$ has distinct two roots $1,\ i$ so that it is separable polynomial.

Hence spliting field is $K={\bf Z}_2(i)=\{ 0,\ 1,\ i\}$

Over $K$, $f(x)$ has factorization $(x-1)(x-i)=x^2+x+ix+1\neq f(x)$

Why does such phenomenon happen ?

**More detailed explanation** :

Consider ${\bf R}$-case. For $f(x)=x^2+1 \in {\bf R}[x]$ has a root $\pm i$ so that we have an extension $$ K={\bf R}(i)={\bf C}={\bf R}[x]/(x^2+1)$$
and we have factorization $$ f(x)=(x+i)(x-i)$$ over $K$.

I want to do similar thing in case $F={\bf Z}_2$

Comment: $i$ is not an element of ${\bf Z}_2$! In fact, $X^2+1$ has $1$ as its only root. Note $f=(X+1)(X+1)$ splits over ${\bf Z}_2$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "$f$ has factorization..." As you note immediately afterwards that is NOT $f$. Of course this is ignoring what Mr. Tamaroff pointed out above.

Comment: @ Tamaroff : My additional question is : Which polynomial makes ${\bf Z}_2(i)$ to be a splitting field over ${\bf Z}_2$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by $i$? There are many things wrong with your statements. The polynomial $(x+1)^2$ has $x=1$ as its only root, it doesn't have distinct roots. Since the root has multiplicity two, the polynomial is not separable. The splitting field of $x^2+1$ over ${\Bbb F}_2$ is ${\Bbb F}_2$ itself, since it contains the root $1$. The notation ${\bf Z}_2(i)$ doesn't seem to make sense, and there isn't even any ring with characteristic two and precisely three elements.

Comment: If you mean to be denoting $\{a+bi:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_2\}$, then the correct notation would be $\mathbb{F}_4=\mathbb{Z}_2[i]$. This is a four element set though, $\mathbb{Z}_2[i]=\{0,1,i,1+i\}$

Comment: In response to your edit: the analogy breaks down because $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\bf R$ but it splits completely over ${\bf F}_2$. As a result, you need to adjoin an element to $\bf R$ to get $x^2+1$ to factor, but you don't need to do anything to ${\bf F}_2$ to get it to factor.

Comment: @anon : Thank you. I see difference, irreducibility.

Comment: @Stella That is not a field, if you mean to have $i^2=-1=1$.

Comment: @Mike It might be my fault, since I thought we were talking about $\{0,1,X,1+X\}$ with $i$ playing the role as $X$, not as $i^2=-1$, but $i^2=i+1$, and made a comment accordingly, which I then deleted when I spotted my mistake.

Comment: @ Pedro : Thank you for your comment. From Mike's answer, I know that $K=\{ 0,\ 1,\ \alpha,\ 1+\alpha\}$ is a splitting. And irreducible polynomial $f(x)=x^2+x+1$ has factorization $(x-\alpha)(x-1-\alpha)$ in $K$.

Comment: Oh, yes, I, like Mike, was using i as a formal symbol because that's what the OP used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no $\Bbb Z_2(i)$; it's nonsense to adjoin a complex number. Colloquially, though, this is meant to mean the splitting field of $x^2+1$ over $\Bbb Z_2$ - but this is $ \Bbb Z_2$, as $x^2+1=x^2+2x+1=(x+1)^2 \in \Bbb Z_2[x]$. There is, however, a field of characteristic 2 with 4 elements: the splitting field of $x^2+x+1$ over $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: Thank you : The field is $\{ 0,\ 1,\ x,\ 1+x\}$, and $x$ has an inverse $1+x$ with $x(x+1)=1$, which is stated in Pedro's comment.

Comment: Yep! $\ \ \ \ $